# Get the data stored in address using the * operator

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
int i = 17;
int *addressOfI = &i;
printf("the int stored at addressOfI is %d\n", *addressOfI);
```

The question is: If I can get the data stored in addressOfI using the * operator, why it doesn't works for type NSString? like following:

```
NSString *string = @"Hello world!"
printf("the NSString stored at string is %@\n", *string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why it doesn't works for type NSString?

Because `NSString` is an Objective-C object and not a primitive type.  The `NSString *` pointer actually points to a `struct objc_object` which provides the framework for the object system.  You can probably "see" some primitive types within this framework (i.e. members of `objc_object`) however it's supposed to be a *black box* to normal developers.

The actual reason your second piece of code will crash is that the `%@` format specifier expects to call the `description` method on the object you pass in as an argument and you have dereferenced that object pointer so it's no longer a valid object pointer.